# Agregar valores seleccionados desde un formulario al estado de un componente React

Tags: formularios, react-hooks, html-select, input-type

necesito que mi estado en React vaya cambiando según la información que entra a diferentes inputs. Mi estado es un objeto y no logro establecer a mis opciones seleccionadas como el valor de una de las propiedades de mi estado.
Mi estado es el siguiente:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState(
{
    name: '',
    genres: []
});
```

La función que va cambiando el estado según lo que se ingresa por los inputs es esta:

```
function handdleInputChange(e) {
    if (e.target.value === 'genres') {
        let arr = input[e.target.name];
        setInput({...input, [e.target.name]: arr.concat(e.target.value),})
    }
    setInput({...input, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
```

Los inputs son:

```
return (
    <form onSubmit={handdleSubmit}>
        <div>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input  name='name' type='text' 
                      value={input.name} onChange={handdleInputChange}
                      autoComplete='off' />
        </div>
        <div>
                <label>Genres</label>
                <select name='Genres' size='5' multiple>
                    <option selected value='selected'>-Add Multiple Genres-</option>
                    {allGenres.map(g => (
                        <option name='genres' value={g.name} multiple 
                                onChange={handdleInputChange}>{g.name}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
        </div>
    </form>
)
```

En un principio traigo desde un estado con Redux todos los géneros posibles, y lo llamo 'allGenres', es a quien le hago el .map().
No logro que la propiedad "genres" de mi estado agrege las opciones seleccionadas desde el tag  Muchas gracias por su ayuda.